# Mysql PREG_REPLACE нужно заменить вхождение между двумя строками

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка в базе "lorem ipsum **sit amit** "
Мне нужно заменить вхождение между символами ** на него же с исправлениями

```
Вот что я пытаюсь сделать
"**sit amit**" => "<tag>sit amit</tag>" 


UPDATE test_table SET field = REGEXP_REPLACE(field,'[\*\*(.*?)\*\*]', 'что здесь?');
запрос заменяет каждый символ звездочки на новую строку, мне же нужно ** => <tag>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `REGEXP_REPLACE(field, '\\*\\*(.*?)\\*\\*', '<tag>\\1</tag>');`

Comment: Спасибо, вхождения находит корректно, но заменяет на текст '<tag>\\1</tag>' как есть

Comment: Тогда попробуйте `'<tag>$1</tag>'`.

Answer (score 1):

В [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) не нашел описание групп, поэтому может это и не работает, но должно быть вроде:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(field,'\*\*(.*?)\*\*', '<tag>$1</tag>');
```

Если не работает можно в два приема:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(field,'^\*\*', '<tag>');
REGEXP_REPLACE(field,'\*\*$', '</tag>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(field, '\\*\\*(.*?)\\*\\*', '<tag>$1</tag>');
```

Шаблон получается `\*\*(.*?)\*\*`:

- `\*\*` - `**`
- `(.*?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: ноль и более символов, отличных от символов перехода на новую строку, как можно меньше
- `\*\*` - `**`

`$1` — обратная ссылка на значение первой подмаски.